# Running multi container application dependent on other containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am fairly new to docker.

My problem is - I have a multi container application(zookeeper, kafka, producer, consumer) in which I want to run the producer and the consumer containers only after the zookeeper and kafka containers are up and running. How to edit the docker-compose file and achieve that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `depends_on` instruction only allows you to manage the *starting order*.
However, **it does not wait for your service to be up and running** before triggering the next.

If you want to start a service after your dependance is up, then you'll have to look at tools like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) or [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize).

You can find more info on the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the **depends_on** directive in the docker-compose documentation.

__ from the docs __

> depends_on Express dependency between services, Service dependencies
>   cause the following behaviors:
>
> docker-compose up starts services in dependency order. In the
>   following example, db and redis are started before web.
>
> docker-compose up SERVICE automatically includes SERVICE’s
>   dependencies. In the following example, docker-compose up web also
>   creates and starts db and redis.
>
> docker-compose stop stops services in dependency order. In the
>   following example, web is stopped before db and redis.

Simple example:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
```